how do i print lives only when letter in word choice is not equal to user guess
import random
import gamename
import hangmanpics
import wordslist

print(gamename.hangman_log)
word_choice = random.choice(wordslist.random_words)
print(word_choice)
word_length = len(word_choice)

display = []
lives = 0

for letter in word_choice:
    display += "_"


print(''.join(display))
end_game = False

while not end_game:
    user_guess = input("Guess a letter in word: ")
    for position in range(word_length):
        letter = word_choice[position]
        if user_guess == letter:
            #lives -= 1
            display[position] = letter

    if user_guess != letter:
        lives += 1
        print(hangmanpics.HANGMANPICS[lives])
        if lives == 6:
            end_game = True
            print("You lost")
            print(f"the word is{word}")

    if "_" not in display:
        end_game = True
        print('You won')
    word = ''.join(display)
    print(f"The word is {word}")

I'm working on this hangman project but I'm having a problem with adding lives only when the user guess is not in the word and also print the hangman pics when its the user's entry in not in the word choice but if the letter in the letter guessed it shouldn't add lives or print hangman pics. How do I do it?

You don't need a loop to check if the input is in the word. Use position = word_choice.find(user_guess) to get the position of the match. If this is -1, the guess is not found.

shorter display = ["_"] * word_length

you should check if user_guess not in word_choice: instead of if user_guess != letter:

shorter for position, letter in enumerate(word_choice):

You should check
    if user_guess in word_choice:

instead of if user_guess != letter:
Something like this
while not end_game:
    user_guess = input("Guess a letter in word: ")

    user_guess = user_guess.strip().lower()

    if user_guess in display:
        print(f'Again the same letter: {user_guess}')
        continue  # go back to beginning of loop
        
    if user_guess in word_choice:
        lives -= 1
        for position, letter in enumerate(word_choice):
            if user_guess == letter:
                display[position] = letter

    #if user_guess not in word_choice:
    else:
        lives += 1
        print(hangmanpics.HANGMANPICS[lives])
        if lives == 6:
            end_game = True
            print("You lost")
            print(f"the word is{word}")

    # ... other code ...

